# Azure API Management Subscription Expiration

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am setting up Azure API Management with 2 different products that offer different access and restrictions to the underlying API.

Ideally I would like subscriptions for each product to have a different length of time that the user can access them for before it needs to be renewed.  I am not finding any type of auto-expiration date for subscriptions when I approve them.

Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

You can create product specific policies that check the time since the subscription was created and deny access if necessary. See context.Subscription.StartDate here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dn910913.aspx

Comment: I have done that for the Free Tier which is supposed to last for 90 days.  But I don't think that will work for a paid subscription that is for a year because when they renew the subscription (payment offline) the Subscription.StartDate will stay the same and so the API would still deny access.  I'm not sure how to get around that issue for the paid product.